# Merging an account caused my username to change on a site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, display-names, merge-accounts

When [my Information Security account](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/128225/user598527?tab=profile) was merged to a secondary (IS) account, *at least* my [Super User username](https://superuser.com/users/598527/user598527?tab=profile) was changed to this secondary account's username (username history, "recent names", is available if you're a moderator). Is this a bug?

I was able to restore my original username globally in account settings, fortunately.

Comment: Which account is the older?

Comment: @user598527:  The original account.

Answer (score 6):

When the merge took place, your other account has profiles on the following sites too:

- Super User
- Web Applications
- Arqade
- Information Security

Merging the network account together causes a merge to occur on each individual site where both accounts have a profile also. Merges always go into the profile that has the lower user ID, and whatever display name, profile picture, and other information that is in use on that lower-ID profile is what gets kept after the merge ***unless*** that information hasn't been changed yet on that profile.

Since your profile with the lower user ID still used the default display name, and your other profile had a display name explicitly set, the display name was copied over as a part of the merge.